# Monitor Google Cloud Via Service Account (Java)

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform

How to access Google Cloud environment using only service account email address?

I saw many documentation of google api. But everywhere I found that, to authenticate google cloud via service account: need email address, and key file.

But I want to authenticate google cloud by using only service account email address.

Is this possible??

Comment: No, you can't use *just* the service account email address. That's not a secret in itself - if I can guess your service account email address, do you want me to have access to everything your service account can do?